# Deleting snapshot: read beyond end of object

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

I was deleting some snapshots in VMWare workstation. I get the following error message:

> Unable to clean up deleted file:
>
> Read beyond end of object.

[image: Screenshot]

The snapshot is no longer there, but I wonder whether the disk space has actually been freed. How to free up disk space that remains due to above error message?

I have tried:

- [VMWare KB 1009484](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1009484), but it's about cloning. I get the error when deleting a snapshot.
- A VMWare forum [thread with the same error](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/490743), but it's about cloning and unanswered.

I'm currently using VMWare Workstation 12.5.6 build 5528349 on Windows 7 Pro SP1. I'm doing this on a local disk and there should be enough free space (1.23 TB free, the VMs are much smaller than that).

Comment: update to version 14.1 and look if the issue is fixed there.

Comment: @magicandre1981: how should I know? The snapshot does not exist any more already in version 12. How should I find out whether there are ophan files on my disk or not? Does version 14 have a special integrity check feature?

Comment: I don't know, simply try it out with last software version which is 14.1

Comment: @magicandre1981: but *what* should I try? I cannot delete the same snapshots again, because they are gone. I don't see them in Snapshot manager

Comment: manually delete snapshot entries in VMX file with notepad (backup the file first)

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error when attempting to clone a VMware Virtual Machine.
What I found that worked was shutting down the VMware instance then from the menu run VM > Manage > Clean Up Disks.
After performing a cleanup the Virtual Machine cloned without an error.